# one area tag showing two href files

Tags: javascript, html

I have a two php pages one is creating a table another one is creating a graph. My index.html file is supposed to call both of them and show both the table and graph on the main page when some one clicks on the image. I have used this code

```
<div id="upload_target"   ></div>
<div id="upload_target2"   ></div>


<img src="image.png" alt="hello"  usemap="#use" >
<map name="use">
    <area shape="poly" coords="..." href="table.html" target="upload_target">
    <area shape="poly" coords="..." href="graph.html" target="upload_target2">
</map>
```

so when the user clicks on area_1 table is shown in "upload_target" and when he clicks on area_2, it is shown in section "upload_target2".

But I wanna just have one area tag for both of them so when he clicks on image both can be shown some thing like this:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="hello"  usemap="#use" >
    <map name="use">
        <area shape="poly" coords="..." href="table.html" target="upload_target" href="graph.html" target="upload_target2">

    </map>
```

is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use Ajax? Without it, you get a single request per clicky.

Comment: @Dave Newton I use Ajax for showing the table in graph.php file, how should I use it here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 100%.  When the user clicks on the area tag, you want the href source loaded into 2 separate elements?  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Kyle I want table.html to load into upload_target element and at the same time graph .html to load into upload_target2 element

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, attributes must be unique on HTML elements.  You may be able to accomplish this with an onclick event on the area element.

For example, you might try the following HTML:

```
<div id="upload_target1"></div>
<div id="upload_target2"></div>
<img src="image.png" alt="hello"  usemap="#use" />
    <map name="use">
        <area shape="poly" coords="..." target1="table.html"  target2="graph.html" onclick="return loadContent(this);" />
    </map>
```

With the javascript function:

```
function loadContent(ele) {
    var target1 = ele.getAttribute('target1'), 
        target2 = ele.getAttribute('target2');
    //Make 2 AJAX requests to load the information
    //If you are using jQuery, it is as simple as
    $('#upload_target1').load(target1);
    $('#upload_target2').load(target2);
    return false; //Prevent the default action from happening
}
```

Hope this helps.